# How to access the selected label and selected description in jsf selectOneMenu where selectOneMenu is bound with javax.faces.model.SelectItem objects?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

This is for JSF 2.0 (Kindly note - this is mojerra implementation and I am not using Icefaces, myfaces etc.)

Consider I just have a drop down in my my form and the dropdown is bound with a List of SelectItems objects which stores value,label and description.

In my Value change actionlistener event how can I access the selected value,label and description. I am able to access only the selected value?

Sample code-

In my xhtml - the dropdown is -

```
<h:selectOneMenu onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{person.changeDD}" value="#{person.selectedValue}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{person.lists}"></f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

where person is the name of the bean

ModelBean-

```
@ManagedBean(name="person")
@SessionScoped
public class PersonBean implements Serializable{

private String selectedValue;

private List<SelectItem> lists=new ArrayList<SelectItem>(); 
public PersonBean() {
        lists=new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        lists.add(new SelectItem("1","India","desc1"));
        lists.add(new SelectItem("2","canada","desc2"));
        lists.add(new SelectItem("3","america","desc3"));
    }
//getters and setters


public void changeDD(ValueChangeEvent vce) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("in value change");
        System.out.println("New value-->"+vce.getNewValue().toString());
//I have access only to the selected value and not to the description and label

    }
}
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *In my Value change actionlistener event how can I access the selected value,label and description. I am able to access only the selected value?*

That's indeed also only what's been sent by a HTML `<select>` element. 
You need to maintain a mapping of the available values and `SelectItem`s yourself.

```
@ManagedBean(name="person")
@SessionScoped
public class PersonBean implements Serializable {

    private String selectedValue;
    private Map<String, SelectItem> availableValues;
    private List<SelectItem> lists; 

    public PersonBean() {
        availableValues = new LinkedHashMap<String, SelectItem>();
        availableValues.put("1", new SelectItem("1", "India", "desc1"));
        availableValues.put("2", new SelectItem("2", "canada", "desc2"));
        availableValues.put("3", new SelectItem("3", "america", "desc3"));
        lists = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(availableValues.values());
    }

    public void changeDD(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        String selectedValue = (String) event.getNewValue();
        SelectItem selectedItem = availableItems.get(newValue);
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a zillion Balusc. God bless you :)

Comment: Yes, thanks . I tried to mark the answer as useful but it requires 15 reputation :(

Comment: Then why there is no equals & hasCode method in source code of SelectItem? it would be easier to get the SelectItem from the list.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>you can do that by having variables for them and creating getters and setters for the variables</strike>

in your bean for eg. for the description create in your bean

```
  private String description;

  public String getDescription(){
       return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String desc){
       description = desc;
  }
```

and similarly for any variable.

Sorry i misunderstood

you can do

```
//String selectedvalue
SelectItem selectedValue;//create getters setter
public void changeDD(ValueChangeEvent vce) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("in value change");
    System.out.println("New value-->"+vce.getNewValue().toString());
    String description = selectedValue.getDescription();

}
}
```

Comment: Hello ChingPing- Thanks for the prompt answer. However the above implementation throws a runtime exception 
SEVERE: JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught during processing of PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3 :java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem
6-Oct-2011 1:43:19 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
SEVERE: /default.xhtml @26,123 valueChangeListener="#{person.changeDD}": java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem

:( :(

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to use Custom objects as values for your SelectItems and implement Custom Converter for them:
http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html

In JSF 2 you can implement custom convertors easily like this:
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/